# ReportViewer reportpath .rdlc from database

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I am saving physically .rdlc(xml) file in the database column. The column datatype is 'image'.  How can I read this column and dynamically set it to the ReportViewer control? Please let me know if there are any examples.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a very similar question regarding getting a reportviewer report definition from a sql server database.

[Opening Remote RDL with .NET Report Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801284/opening-remote-rdl-with-net-report-viewer-c/8801997#8801997)

Plus, personally due to the size of some RDLC files, I would cache them to disk anyway if there is a lot of traffic to get better performance.